# ACCESS-VBA. Ошибка при работе с EXCEL "Named argument not found"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Access 2016. 
подключаюсь к Excel

```
Private Sub btnFile_Click()
Dim appExcel As Object
Dim a as range
Dim wbk As Variant 'Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Variant 'Excel.Worksheet
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set wks = wbk.Sheets.Add(After:=wbk.Sheets(wbk.Sheets.Count))
Set wks = wbk.Sheets("Bilans")
With wks
For col = 2 To 5
        Set a = wks.Range("B" & col & ":Y" & col)
       maxValue = appExcel.WorksheetFunction.Max(a)
       avgValue = appExcel.WorksheetFunction.Average(a)
       a.Replace What:=maxValue, _ 
       replacement:=Replace(CDbl(avgValue), ".", ","), LookAt:=xlWhole, _ 
       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Next col
```

на моменте `a.Replace`получаю ошибку:
    `Named argument not found`
Как пофиксить?

upd

```
Private Sub btnFile_Click()
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim a as range
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set wks = wbk.Sheets.Add(After:=wbk.Sheets(wbk.Sheets.Count))
```

на `wbk.Sheets.Count`ошибка `Method or data member not found`.

Что смущает, так это то что месяц назад база работала.

Comment: может не `replacement` а `Replacement`?

Comment: Имена именованных параметров регистронезависимы.

Comment: @Akina точно! В VBA же регистронезависимость)

Comment: Проходить код пошагово (`F8`) и смотреть значения переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете позднее связывание. При этом именованные константы недоступны. Определите их на уровне модуля/процедуры, либо используйте их численные значения. Или перейдите на раннее связывание.

**UPD:**

> на wbk.Sheets.Count ошибка Method or data member not found

Ну если учесть, что индексация идёт с нуля, то в книге из, скажем, 3 листов, они имеют индексы 0, 1 и 2, и искать лист с индексом 3 несколько самонадеянно...

Comment: Не сработало. В чем я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Проблема не в количестве листов. !http://imgshare.free.fr/uploads/a608cea7b2.png

Comment: Проверьте референсы. Проверьте наличие и целостность структуры через браузер объектов. В режиме отладки проверьте, что лежит в объектных переменных. И следовало бы делать скриншот так, чтобы были видны дефиниции переменных... а ещё лучше оформить минимальный код в виде отдельной процедуры. Заодно посмотрите в процессах на поведение хост-процесса Excel.

Comment: @Akina, *индексация идёт с нуля*  - проверяем:в  Excel (в книге 3 листа, n = 3):  `n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count: 
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name`, или `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets(0).Name` (ошибка). в Access по-другому?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема возникла в Access2016 после последнего обновления. В предыдущих версиях все работает как запрограммировано. Не знаю окончательное ли решение или же через время опять не будет работать, но сейчас отрабатывает нормально после выноса кода с обработчика нажатия кнопки модуля формы в отдельный модуль.